# How to connect edge devices to AWS Greengrass core device running version 2

Tags: aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass

In AWS Greengrass v2 developer guide, [Move from AWS IoT Greengrass Version 1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/move-from-v1.html), it says, `AWS IoT Greengrass V2 currently doesn't support connected devices, also called Greengrass devices.`

Wonder what would be the recommended ways (for the time being) to connect edge devices, such as ESP devices, to the Greengrass core device running Greengrass version 2.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found on AWS IoT forum [an explanation from Farad at AWS](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=971726) in Feb 2021:

Greengrass V2 unfortunately does not provide `GGAD` (Greengrass Aware Device) yet. They are actively working on addressing this gap and hope to release it in the coming months. Until that time, you can use Greengrass version 1 or you could use this [example MQTT Bridge code for Greengrass V2](https://github.com/aws-greengrass/aws-greengrass-component-examples/tree/main/mqtt-bridge) as a skeleton for implementing your own MQTT broker on V2 in order to support remote devices.